# Translate english to local language in java

Tags: java

I want to know implement in my Java project(uses Netbeans IDE) payment option.

So the data can be insert to system in english,but it has be printed a bill in Sinhala(Sri lankan language) should be  in offline(Not using google API). 
Is there any java libraray or any support to translate english to local language.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to automatically translate the messages or use pre-prepared translations based on language settings?

For the second option there is built in support within Java.

Look at MessageFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

And Resource Bundles: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html

There is a Trail about i18n here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

I can't recommend automatic translation for something like this as it is still not completely reliable. For something like a bill you really need to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

### Try Spring MVC Internationalization

In Spring MVC application, comes with few “LocaleResolver” to support the internationalization or multiple languages features,just maintance *.properties file 
[spring tutorial here](http://simplespringtutorial.com/i18n.html)